# C# LINQ Group by

Tags: c#, linq, average

I'm new to C# and trying to answer some LINQ questions. I'm stuck on 1st marked as difficult...

**Q:** What were the top 10 origin airports with the largest average​ departure delays, including the values of these delays? (Hint: use group by)?

I have a **list** named "Flights" populated with more than 20000 objects of **class** "FlightInfo".

Properties of the FlightInfo class are:
*string Carrier, string Origin, string Destination, int DepartureDelay, int ArrivalDelay, int Cancelled, int Distance*.

I understand that I should group FlightInfo by FlightInfo.Origin and than average each of these groups by FlightInfo.DepartureDelay and than show 10 with the highest average delay, but beside grouping I'm completely stuck on how to proceed further.

Thank you in advance for any help!

---

Here is the example of one of previous questions that I was able to answer:

**Q:** The weighted arrival delay of a flight is its arrival delay divided the distance. What  was the flight with the largest weighted arrival delay out of Boston, MA?

**A:**

```
var weighted = (from FlightInfo in Flights
               where FlightInfo.Origin == "Boston MA"
               orderby (FlightInfo.ArrivalDelay / FlightInfo.Distance) descending
               select FlightInfo).Take(1);
```

Comment: Side note for the answered question: `Take` returns the `IEnumerable<T>` if you want `T` instance, use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Yes, I see that when I use `First` I can get to the properties without using `foreach` loop. Thank you, I couldn't understand before why I can't `Console.WriteLine(weighted.Origin)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var topTen = flights.
            GroupBy(g => g.Origin).
            Select(g => new { Origin = g.Key, AvgDelay = g.ToList().Average(d => d.DepartureDelay) }).
            OrderByDescending(o => o.AvgDelay).
            Take(10);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is complete solution to my question. Now since I'm a novice I still can't grasp the syntax, it seems I'm jumping ahead. I have so much to learn...

Comment: First of you group by a key. Linq makes a dictionary where key is the key you grouped by and the value is the list of those objects(a bit different than SQL). After that we do a select for each of these groups where we make a new anonymous object that has properties Origin and AvgDelay. Avg delay is the average of all the objects in the list for that particular key. After that it is easy - order by AvgDelay and take first 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the logic, but no matter how I try, I can't add another property to Select. Let's say I would also like to show Carrier.
`Select(g => new { 
Origin = g.Key,
AvgDelay = g.ToList().Average(d => d.DepartureDelay),
Company = g.ToList().????(p => p.Carrier)????
 })`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
var top10 = Flights.GroupBy(g=>g.Origin) // groupby origin 
                  .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Sum(f=> f.ArrivalDelay / f.Distance))  // Get the weighted delay for each fight and use for ordering.
                  .Select(x=>x.Key)  //Airport or Origin (Modify with what you want)
                  .Take(10)
                  .ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = flights
    .GroupBy(f => f.Origin)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Average(f => f.DepartureDelay))        
    .Take(10)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        AirportName = g.Key,
        Flights = g.ToList()
    });
```

The last `.Select` parameter depends on what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gives correct, but incomplete answer. Since I'm novice I was unable to add another property by myself (departure delay).